# how to filter the array value based on sort array before foreach loop

Tags: php

```
productid    Qty    SupplierId 
M0001        -      S0001
M0002        -      S0002
M0001        -      S0001
M0002        -      S0002

Quantity is an input. manually given by user


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$Product=$data->Product;
$quantity=$data->quantity;
$suppliername=$data->suppliername;

sort($suppliername); //S0001,S0001,S0002,S0002

            foreach($suppliername as $index => $value)
            {   
                $ProductArr = $Product[$index];
                $QtyhArr = $quantity[$index];
                $SupplierArr = $suppliername[$index];

                $qry_resArr = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Table(Supplier,Product,Qty) VALUES (?,?,?)"); 
                $qry_resArr->execute(array($SupplierArr,$ProductArr,$QtyhArr));
            }
```

how to filter the array value based on sort array before foreach loop. I need to pass the product,qty value based on the sorted array. how to do this?. Thanks you

```
Expected result: I need to pass into query below format
S0001,M0001,300
S0001,M0001,70
S0002,M0002,150
S0002,M0002,100
```

Comment: checkout my answer, you use should `asort()` instead of `sort()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the index of the values while sorting so you should use [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) instead of `sort()`

So it would be like

```
asort($suppliername);

foreach($suppliername as $index => $value){
    $ProductArr  = $Product[$index];
    $QtyhArr     = $quantity[$index];
    $SupplierArr = $suppliername[$index];
}
```

it gives output as you needed

Comment: Yup. Its working, Thanks you. @Thamaraiselvam What is difference between sort and asort?

Comment: asort does not change the index so even values gets sorted index remains the same. checkout here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php more info